# Correctly overload assignment operator for classes with pointer members

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading

**Correct me if I'm wrong:**

I understand that when having a class with members that are pointers, a copy of a class object will result in that the pointers representing the same memory address. This can result in changes done to one class object to affect all copies of this object.

A solution to this can be to overload the **=** operator. Given the example below, with an attempt to create a dynamic array class, why does making changes to **MyArray1** change **MyArray2**:

**Array Class:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Array
{
public:
    Array(int N){               //constructor sets size of array
         size = N;
         arr = new int[N];
    }

    ~Array();

    int size;    //array elements
    int *arr;    //dynamic array pointer

    //fill array with random values between 1 and 100
    void fillArray() {
         for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
              {arr[i] = std::rand()%100;}
    }

    //print out array to console
    void printArray() {
         for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
             { std::cout << arr[i] << " ";}
             std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    //overload = operator
    Array &operator=(Array arr2) {
        std::swap(size, arr2.size);
        std::swap(arr, arr2.arr);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
 #include "Array.h"
 #include <iostream>

int main(){
    Array MyArray1(8), MyArray2(8);

    MyArray1.fillArray();
    MyArray2 = MyArray1;

    std::cout << "Print out arrays:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "MyArray1: "; MyArray1.printArray();
    std::cout << "MyArray2: "; MyArray2.printArray();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    MyArray1.arr[5] = 1000;
    std::cout << "MyArray2: "; MyArray2.printArray();

    MyArray1.fillArray();
    std::cout << "MyArray2: "; MyArray2.printArray();    

    return 0;
}
```

**Example output:**

```
Print out arrays:
MyArray1: 41 67 34 0 69 24 78 58
MyArray2: 41 67 34 0 69 24 78 58

MyArray2: 41 67 34 0 69 1000 78 58
MyArray2: 62 64 5 45 81 27 61 91
```

As seen above, changes made to MyArray1, changes MyArray2. I assume the overloading of **=** is wrong, but how would I write it correctly?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Chris Dodd in the comments, I realized it's just to implement a copy constructor like this in my class:

```
Array(const Array &arr2){
        size = arr2.size;
        arr = new int[size];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr2.arr[i];
        }
}
```

Comment: You've violated the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: Yes, I was realising that, that's why I deleted my comment same time as you anwered! Thank you, I will give it a shot:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is more than one issue with your code. Most importantly, as pointed out in the comment to to the question, except for writing your own assignment operator, you need to write your copy constructor as well (and implement a destructor).

Second thing is, that your assignment operator takes argument by value instead of by reference, which causes default copy constructor to create a copy of your `MyArray1` before it's passed to assignment operator. This is where the direct source of your problem lays.

Another thing is that your assignment operator behaves like a move assignment instead of copy assignment, meaning it replaces the original item's values with its current (default) value.

Lastly, you really want to implement the destructor, so that it deletes your array instead of just leaking it.

Summing up, you want something like this (edit: copy assignment checks inspired by Timothy's answer):

```
class Array
{
public:
    Array(int N)
    {
         size = N;
         arr = new int[N];
    }

    //destructor
    ~Array()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    //copy constructor
    Array(const Array& arr2)
    {
        size = arr2.size;
        arr = new int[size];
        std::memcpy(arr, arr2.arr, size);
    }

    //overload = operator
    Array& operator=(const Array& arr2) 
    {
        if (this == &arr2)
            return *this; //self assignment
        if (arr != NULL)
            delete[] arr; //clean up already allocated memory

        size = arr2.size;
        arr = new int[size];
        std::memcpy(arr, arr2.arr, size);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int size;    //array elements
    int *arr;    //dynamic array pointer
};
```

Comment: I noticed by changing my assignement operator to take a reference, and reruning the code, MyArray1 "loses" all it's information after doing: MyArray2 = MyArray1

Comment: "Second thing is, that your assignment operator takes argument by value instead of by reference" It is the copy any swap idiom.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, you are obviously right, I doubt OP understood how it worked, though (because of not implementing copy constructor)

Comment: can u please explain why compiler says `error: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Werror=misleading-indentation]
   31 |                       if (this == &arr2)`

Answer (score 1):

So, I see three issues.

1. You should really have a copy constructor. You never know what optimizations your compiler might make (changing assignment to copy-constructor, etc...).
2. you should check for self-assignment when assigning. When doing the assignment you want to get rid of your old data and replace it with the new.
   If you do self assignment, you'll run into errors (aka delete your data before you reassign to yourself) plus it's extra work you don't need to do.
3. you don't handle your dynamically allocated data when you call the destructor. This will cause a memory-leak and for long running programs becomes a large problem.

Code Updates:

```
~Array(){
  if (arr != NULL)
    delete arr;
}

Array(const Array& arr2){
  size = arr2.size;
  arr = new int[Size];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){ //Copy each array element into new array
    arr[i] = arr2.arr[i];
  }
}

Array& operator= (const Array& arr2){
  if (this == &arr2){ return *this; } //make sure you aren't self-assigning
  if (arr != NULL){ delete arr; } // get rid of the old data
  //same as copy constructor from here
  size = arr2.size;
  arr = new int[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    arr[i] = arr2.arr[i];
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: Re. point 2, OP is using the copy and swap idiom. That would be robust against self-assignment. But it is broken because of the copy constructor.

Comment: Fair enough. Although for large arrays that causes a lot of extra work for self assignment.

Comment: You should use delete [] for array deletion.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid all of these if you want to make = only but not
Array `MyArray1=MyArray2` because it also needs a copy constructor
you can do this

```
Array& operator =(Array&arr)
```

passing by reference solve the problem but if you want to do

```
Array MyArray1(MyArray2) ;  or     Array MyArray1=MyArray2
```

you need a copy constructor

and if you want selfassignment you must check

```
if(this=&arr) {return *this;}
```